# Divide the navbar into 3 equal parts

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 menu items in my navbar. I want the entire nav to be divided into 3 parts for my 3 menus. I tried with the following code but the last menu item takes bit extra space than others. How do i fix it?

```css
 .navbar {
         border : 1px solid #ffffff;
     }
     #intr1, #intr2 {
         border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
     }
     .menuLabel {
         text-align: center;
         font-size: 17px;
         font-weight: bold;
         color: #ffffff;
     }
```

```html
 <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-header ">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav container">
              <li class="col-md-4" id="intr1"><a href="#"><div class="menuLabel">INTERIOR DESIGN&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></div></a></li>
              <li class="col-md-4" id="intr2"><a href="#"><div class="menuLabel">INTERIOR DESIGN&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></div></a></li>
              <li class="col-md-4" id="intr3"><a href="#"><div class="menuLabel">INTERIOR DESIGN&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></div></a></li>
             </ul>
           </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you a lot:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav customnavbarnav">
                <li class="customlist"><a href="#">Link </a>
                </li>
                <li class="customlist"><a href="#">Link </a>
                </li>
                <li class="customlist"><a href="#">Link </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!-- /.navbar navbar-default -->
```

CSS:

```
.customnavbarnav{
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center;
}
.customlist{
    width: 33.33333333333333%
}
```

Comment: this saved my time a lot. I was looking for nav collapse feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try with something like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
     <div class="container-fluid">
       <ul>
         <li class="col-md-4" id="intr1">
           <a href="#">
             <div class="menuLabel">INTERIOR DESIGN&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></div>
           </a>
         </li>
         <li class="col-md-4" id="intr2">
           <a href="#">
             <div class="menuLabel">INTERIOR DESIGN&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></div>
           </a>
         </li>
         <li class="col-md-4" id="intr3">
           <a href="#">
             <div class="menuLabel">INTERIOR DESIGN&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></div>
           </a>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `.container` class on the `.navbar-nav` because that is causing you to have 15px right padding which throws off the evenness.

Comment: Tried this but the menu items occupies only half the width of the navbar. The other half is left blank.